# How do I configure SQL Server Management Studio Intelisense to ignore case

Tags: ssms

The way we have our db configured, case does not matter, but in the query editor intelisense  is using case much to my frustration. I like that autocomplete feature of intelisense but I have had to disable it until I can find a way to get it to ignore case.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your using Sql Server 2008, Intellisense in SSMS 2008 R2 is case sensitive but T-SQL itself may not.

It was marked as fixed for later versions.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/672196/t-sql-is-not-case-sensitive-but-t-sql-intellisense-is

It have been fixed on SQL 2012. I know because I am using it. You don’t need to upgrade in order to use a new version of the SQMS but you need to have the license for the new version.  SSMS is compatible with older SS Database Engine Instances but the license requires purchasing the new version. 
If you have a MSDN subscription or a SA agreement maybe you already have it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/871cd19f-227a-44af-a702-4dabc00cb74c/sql-server-management-studio-licensing

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/products/products.aspx

[Can I use SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on a 2008 server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29407/can-i-use-sql-server-management-studio-2012-on-a-2008-server)

[image]

P.D.

Workaround suggested by OP : In SSMS, click on Tools->options, then navigate to Text Editor->Transact-SQL->General and uncheck Auto list members and OK. This will prevent SSMS from replacing something that you typed perfectly with something else that is very wrong. You can still manually list members, when you want to by typing Ctrl-Space, choosing what you want from the list and pressing enter to complete what you typed.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008 R2 and I share the same frustration as David Reed in the reference that you provided. I am glad that MS agreed and fixed it. You are 50% of the way to the ultimate answer to my question(How). When they say that they fixed it in the next release of SSMS, what does that mean? Does it mean loading SQL Server 2012, the next version of the database that SSMS came bundled with? Or is there a way for me to obtain a newer release of SSMS using our existing licenses for SQL Server 2008 R2 and not have to upgrade our installed data structures? Thanks so much for the reference!

Comment: I just added the requested information to my original answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Please add this to your answer as a temporary workaround until the new SSMS can be installed.  In SSMS, click on Tools->options, then navigate to Text Editor->Transact-SQL->General and uncheck Auto list members and OK. This will prevent SSMS from replacing something that you typed perfectly with something else that is very wrong. You can still manually list members, when you want to by typing Ctrl-Space, choosing what you want from the list and pressing enter to complete what you typed. Not perfect, but also not frustrating. Now the user is in control again. TX!